# How to dynamically break a line base on screen size?

Tags: html, css, dynamic, line-breaks

Basically, I have center-align text inside a container. When the screen size gets smaller, it breaks into the next line. At some point, only one (or a few) word(s) is in the next line. How can I let it break evenly?

Example:
one two three four five six

When screen size become smaller:
one two three four five
six

How to make it adjust automatically to:
one two three
four five six

When screen size drops even further until the row of text cannot fix two lines, automatically adjusts to:
one two
three four
five six

Comment: You can solve above by using a combination of CSS grid (controling the div layout) and media queries (trigger changes per media device and width).

Answer (score 1):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    div {
         width:150px;
    }
}
```

Learn about media queries:https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp 
you have to write inside `@media screen and (**here**)` from what size of screen you want to change the `width`

Answer (score 1):

Simply give it to spans or divs and set to spans `display: inline-block;`

CSS:

```
.block {
 display: inline-block;
 }
```

HTML:

```
<span class="block">
one two three
</span>
<span class="block">
four five six
</span>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ysk4s1n6/

Answer (score 1):

The attached code-snippet uses "CSS Grid" and is set to auto-fill which means that it fills "one, two, three, four, five, fix" as much as it can. What does not fit on first line, it moves to second line, etc.

This specific setup does not use media query, since the breakpoint is the div as such, not the device width. It is content-responsive rather then device/width-responsive.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:
  repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr))
  ;
  grid-template-areas:
  "div"
  ;
}

.div {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="div">one</div>
    <div class="div">two</div>
    <div class="div">three</div>
    <div class="div">four</div>
    <div class="div">five</div>
    <div class="div">six</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is a good idea. But the minmax(100px, 1fr). How to make it more dynamic, so that longer phrases/words can fit in the 100px? And also to reduce the length as to not have too big gap between words/phrases.

Answer (score 0):

I using this;

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    // codes for tablet
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    // codes for phone
}
```